# Microsoft SQL Server: how can I group by this column? GROUP BY not working for me

Tags: sql-server

I want to group by Quote ID, I am not able to get it to work though. I've been banging my head on this one for a while.

**EDIT: I'm trying to group the Quantity items into one column, so for example if a Quote ID column has 3 items with the same Quote ID but different quantities, I want to display them in the same row in this fashiong - $QuoteID, $QuantityFromRow1, $QuantityFromRow2, $QuantityFromRow3.**

```
SELECT TOP(100) 
    PPV8.dbo.CUSTOMER.ID As [Customer ID]
     , PPV8.dbo.CUSTOMER.NAME As [Customer]
     , PPV8.dbo.CUSTOMER.CITY As City, Null As [PM]
     , PPV8.dbo.CUSTOMER.STATE As State
     , PPV8.dbo.QUOTE_PRICE.QUOTE_ID As [Quote ID]
     , FLOOR(PPV8.dbo.QUOTE_PRICE.QTY) As Quantity
     , PPV8.dbo.QUOTE_LINE.PART_ID As [Part ID]
     , SUBSTRING(PPV8.dbo.QUOTE_LINE.CUSTOMER_PART_ID, 6, 12) As [Style #]
     , PPV8.dbo.QUOTE_LINE.DESCRIPTION As Description
     , PPV8.dbo.QUOTE_PRICE.UNIT_PRICE As [Unit Price]
     , PPV8.dbo.QUOTE_LINE.CREATE_DATE As [Create Date]
     , PPV8.dbo.QUOTE.SALESREP_ID As [Rep]
     , PPV8.dbo.QUOTE.STATUS As [Quote Status]
     , PPV8.dbo.QUOTE.FOLLOWUP_DATE As [Follow Up]
     , PPV8.dbo.QUOTE.EXPECTED_WIN_DATE As [Due Date] 
FROM
    CUSTOMER 
INNER JOIN
    QUOTE ON PPV8.dbo.CUSTOMER.ID = PPV8.dbo.QUOTE.CUSTOMER_ID 
INNER JOIN  
    QUOTE_LINE ON PPV8.dbo.QUOTE.ID = PPV8.dbo.QUOTE_LINE.QUOTE_ID 
INNER JOIN  
    QUOTE_PRICE ON PPV8.dbo.QUOTE_LINE.QUOTE_ID = PPV8.dbo.QUOTE_PRICE.QUOTE_ID 
                AND PPV8.dbo.QUOTE_LINE.LINE_NO = PPV8.dbo.QUOTE_PRICE.QUOTE_LINE_NO 
WHERE 
    PPV8.dbo.QUOTE.STATUS = 'A' 
    AND PPV8.dbo.QUOTE.EXPECTED_WIN_DATE > '20170101' 
ORDER BY
    PPV8.dbo.QUOTE.EXPECTED_WIN_DATE ASC
```

[image: Image of results]

Comment: I'm certain "group by quote id" means something to you because you are intimately familiar with the schema and the data it contains. Unfortunately, it means nothing to everyone else. Did you mean order by? Using a group by clause generally implies some sort of aggregation - is that your goal?

Comment: Do you still want all of those columns after grouping by the QuoteId?  The nature of Group By is that it aggregates data associated with a particular element, in your case the QuoteId.  But, how will it aggregate CustomerId if it is different?  Or Description?  Do you only want one row per QuoteId and are not aggregating any other values?  How are you determining which row to keep/discard?  Please be more explicit in your goal, because it sounds like Group By is not the tool you need to use to achieve it.

Comment: And for the sake of future generations, learn best practices. Be **consistent** is the most important one IMO. Give each table an alias and use the alias to reference every column. Don't refer to customer and to PPV8.dbo.customer - that makes your code difficult to read and encourages mistakes.

Comment: Your question needs to be longer and have more information in it if you expect an answer.

Answer (score 1):

All (non aggregate) columns in the select statement must be included in the group by clause
So you are missing the point of group by